# How to remove MediaWiki Sidebar with Vector skin?

Tags: mediawiki

Adding

```
#p-navigation, #p-tb h5, #p-tb .pBody { display:none }
```

to `MediaWiki:Common.css` removes the toolbox.

I would also like to remove the Sidebar menu which contains

```
What links here
Related changes
Upload file
Special pages
Printable version
Permanent link
```

**Question**

Does anyone know how to remove this, when using the new Vector skin in MediaWiki 0.1.18?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just

```
#p-navigation, #p-tb { display:none }
```

should remove the navigation bar and the toolbox completely, both in Vector and in MonoBook.

Ps. You may also want to take a look at the [Manual:Interface/Sidebar](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInterface/Sidebar) page at mediawiki.org.